# objective c xcode 4.0.2: subclass can't access superclass variables "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, inheritance, scope

I have several classes that are subclasses of one Layer class.. for some reason one of the subclasses acts differently. this is a stripped down version:

```
@interface Layer: CCLayer
{
 GameScene* _scene;
 CCNode* _layerNode;
}
@end

#import "Layer.h"
@interface UILayer: Layer
{
}
@end

@implementation UILayer
-(void) doStuff
{
  [_layerNode addChild:[CCNode node]];  <---gives compile error: "_layerNode was not declared in this scope"
  [_scene playSound];<------gives compile error: "_scene was not declared in this scope"
}
@end
```

I think that gets the basic idea across. I can fix this by doing

```
[[_self _layerNode] addChild:[CCNode node]];
[[_self _scene] playSound];
```

but what I can't figure out is why other subclasses of Layer can access _layerNode and _scene directly? I am guessing that it is a problem with the build settings. Further this problem only happens when I build it for the device (iphone) and not the simulator. let me know if you need more information to answer.

**Edit:**

Oops I wrote it wrong. It should have been `[[self _layerNode] addNode:[CCNode node]]` but I guess the question is why would one subclass have direct access to the ivar `_layerNode` and another have to access it with `[self _layerNode]`.  It is like the UILayer can't find the super class header

Comment: You either need to post the real code or a minimal example that, when compiled, causes the problem.  As written, (a) that code should compile fine but (b) `_self` doesn't make sense.   As described, this sounds like a potential compiler bug.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822518/if-a-subclass-refers-to-a-superclass-ivar-synthesizing-an-unrelated-property-fai

Answer (score 1):

From the docs: [Apple Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html) *(doesn't mention this anymore, but you can find it in [this retired document](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf))*.

> The instance variable is accessible within the class that declares it and within classes that inherit it. All instance variables without an explicit scope directive have `@protected` scope.
>
> However, a public instance variable can be accessed anywhere as if it were a field in a C structure. For example:
>
> `Worker *ceo = [[Worker alloc] init];`
>
> `ceo->boss = nil;`

I have the compilation error using `LLVM GCC 4.2` (for an iOS project, on device):

> error: 'fooInstanceVar' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   and the same one using GCC 4.2 :
>   error: 'fooInstanceVar' undeclared (first use in this function)

I can compile using `LLVM Compiler 2.0` whithout error.

For compiling with `LLVM GCC 4.2` and `GCC 4.2` with the use of `self->`:

> `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.barProperty, self->fooInstanceVar, nil];`
>   in the `doSomethingWithProperty` method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the name. The 'UI' prefix is designated for UIKit classes. Could well be that UILayer is a private UIKit class used by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

If you `@synthesize` ivars, the compiler unhelpfully stops you from accessing them "directly". The fix is relatively easy: Write `self->_layerNode` and `self->_scene`.

I'm assuming your "stripped-down version" compiles fine.

Note that it's also bad form to directly access your superlcass's ivars unless you're aware of its implementation details.

(What's `_self`?)

Comment: @bbum: He doesn't need to; if UILayer synthesizes ivars (and it might; the code is "stripped-down"), in GCC 4.2 it seems to break access to superclass ivars if you don't use `self->`

Comment: I could believe it with GCC.  That compiler is obsolete and shouldn't be used (save for the rare bit of C++ that still relies on GCC-isms).  That particular bug has been fixed in LLVM for quite a long time.

Comment: @bbum: Perhaps Apple is switching to LLVM for various reasons, but I would not call GCC itself "obsolete"; it's merely disappointing that GCC 4.4 isn't supported (and GCC 4.2 wasn't supported until iPhoneOS 3).

Comment: Yah-- I should have been more precise.  4.2 is obsolete and no longer being maintained.   As for 4.4 -- not obsolete, but the GPL v3 is limiting adoption across the commercial space, it seems.