# @properties behave unexpectedly in debugger when @synthesized and then accessed in subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, lldb

I have some @properties that are behaving strangely in the debugger when I `@synthesize` them and then subclass the controller.

The @properties behave as expected when I remove @synthesize.

Here is a basic example, a `ViewController` subclass called `SubClassedViewController`.

## ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSNumber *someNumber;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *someNumber;

@end
```

## ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize someNumber;  //Strange behavior unless I remove this line

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    someNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@end
```

## SubClassedViewController.h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SubClassedViewController : ViewController

@end
```

## SubClassedViewController.m

```
#import "SubClassedViewController.h"

@interface SubClassedViewController ()

@end

@implementation SubClassedViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

## Behavior with @synthesize

Unless I use `self.`, the object points to the subclassed controller, not to the NSNumber:

```
(lldb) po someNumber
$3 = 0x07151a30 <SubClassedViewController: 0x7151a30>
(lldb) po self.someNumber
$4 = 0x08c37f20 123
(lldb) p (int)[someNumber intValue]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before execution.
(lldb) po (UIView*)[someNumber view]
$7 = 0x071574f0 <UIView: 0x71574f0; frame = (0 20; 320 548); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x71575a0>>
```

Note that if I put `NSLog`s in my code, someNumber correctly points to the NSNumber; it is only identified as a SubClassedViewController in lldb (as far as I can tell).

## Behavior without @synthesize

If I comment out `@synthesize` and change the NSNumber creation in ViewController.m to:

```
_someNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];  //I added _ before variable name
```

Then I get the following different behavior (which is the behavior I'd expect)

```
(lldb) po _someNumber
$0 = 0x0717db70 123
(lldb) po self.someNumber
$1 = 0x0717db70 123
(lldb) po self
$2 = 0x071853a0 <SubClassedViewController: 0x71853a0>
```

## Questions

- Is this a bug, or do I misunderstand something?

*If this is a bug* (which is my assumption)...

- Is it a bug in Xcode, the debugger, or the compiler?

*If this is not a bug...*

- I'm using Xcode 4.6.1, which doesn't *require* that I @synthesize
  things.  But shouldn't the behavior of my app be identical whether or
  not I do?
- Why would it ever make sense for a property to point to its "owner"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [If a subclass refers to a superclass ivar, synthesizing an unrelated property fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822518/if-a-subclass-refers-to-a-superclass-ivar-synthesizing-an-unrelated-property-fa) **and** [Property vs. instance variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719788/property-vs-instance-variable) **and** [(Not So) Silly Objective-C inheritance problem when using property - GCC Bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778405/not-so-silly-objective-c-inheritance-problem-when-using-property-gcc-bug)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not "strange behavior". You're getting garbage objects because your code is wrong.

When you remove `@synthesize`, the compiler automatically synthesizes the ivar with the name `_someNumber`. This causes your bad code in `-viewDidLoad` to actually do nothing. Notably, the line

```
someNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];
```

is storing an autoreleased object into an ivar, which means it's going to get released and the ivar will hold a garbage object. The correct fix here is probably to say

```
self.someNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];
```

which will invoke the setter and retain the value for you.

Furthermore, I recommend deleting your ivar declaration entirely and deleting the `@synthesize` as well, and just let the compiler synthesize your ivar.

Comment: That was my initial suspicion, but if that's true, why does `NSLog(@"My Number: %d", someNumber.integerValue);` placed at the end of SubClassedViewController's viewDidLoad return the correct number?

Comment: (That is, if the pointer is garbage, how am I still getting the correct value?)

Comment: @AaronBrager: Because it's not garbage until the autorelease pool is drained. When you're logging it, the autorelease pool hasn't drained yet.